# on hover to trigger bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on my image my popover shows up. I am trying to get it so when I hover over the image the bootstrap pop over shows.

Instead of me clicking on image to make popover show is it possible for me to make it show when hover mouse over image?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('button[data-event=\'showImageDialog\']').attr('data-toggle', 'image').removeAttr('data-event');

    $(document).delegate('button[data-toggle=\'image\']', 'click', function() {
        $('#modal-image').remove();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/filemanager',
            dataType: 'html',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#button-image i').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>');
                $('#button-image').prop('disabled', true);
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#button-image i').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-upload"></i>');
                $('#button-image').prop('disabled', false);
            },
            success: function(html) {
                $('body').append('<div id="modal-image" class="modal">' + html + '</div>');

                $('#modal-image').modal('show');
            }
        }); 
    }); 

    // File Manager

    $(document).delegate('a[data-toggle=\'image\']', 'click', function(e) {
        $('#modal-image').remove();
        e.preventDefault();

        var element = this;

        $(element).popover({
            html: true,
            placement: 'right',
            trigger: 'manual',
            content: function() {
                return '<button type="button" id="button-image" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>';
            }
        });

        $(element).popover('toggle');       

        $('#button-image').on('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'admin/filemanager/?input=' + $(element).parent().find('input').attr('id') + '&element='+ $(element).attr('id'),
                dataType: 'html',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#button-image i').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>');
                    $('#button-image').prop('disabled', true);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#button-image i').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-upload"></i>');
                    $('#button-image').prop('disabled', false);
                },
                success: function(html) {
                    $('body').append('<div id="modal-image" style="" class="modal fade">' + html + '</div>');                                      
                    $('#modal-image').modal('show');
                }
            });

            $(element).popover('hide');
        });
    }); 

});
```

Comment: try using `trigger: 'hover'`

Comment: Did that but this $(document).delegate('a[data-toggle=\'image\']', 'click', function(e) { click causing problem still making me click first